# Performance difference between generic and non generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, .net-4.7.2

Let's say for the sake of the example that we want to work on linear algebra, with different type of matrices. And that we have a custom Matrix class that implements :

```
interface IMatrix
{
    double this[int i, int j] { get; set; }
    int Size { get; }
}
```

I want to implement Matrix multiplication. I was under the impression that both methods :

```
static void Multiply<TMatrix>(TMatrix a, TMatrix b, TMatrix result) where TMatrix : IMatrix
```

and

```
static void Multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix result)
```

(with similar implementation of course) Would internally produce the exact same IL and hence the same performances. It is not the case : the first one is four times slower than the second one. Looking at the IL, it seems the generic one is similar to a call through interface :

```
static void Multiply(IMatrix a, IMatrix b, IMatrix result)
```

Am I missing something ? Is there any way to get the same performances with generics than with a direct call ?

---

*Installed Framework 4.8, Target Framework : 4.7.2 (also tested with .Net Core 3)*

*Method implementation :*

```
static void Multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Size; j++)
        {
            double temp = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a.Size; k++)
            {
                temp += a[i, k] * b[k, j];
            }
            result[i, j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

[Minimal reproductible example](https://github.com/Fread75/stackoverflow-csharp-question-generic/tree/master)

Comment: Possible for you to produce a [mcve] containing a fully executable example that includes both? Easier for others to test.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen good idea, I've edited the question with a link to a minimal reproductible example

Comment: It shouldn't since reflection is probably being used internally.

Comment: There is boxing operation, when you access a matrix element using indexer in generic variant, IL code shows `box          !!0/*TMatrix*/` instructions. It can be a reason of performance drawback, since boxing is quite expensive operation. But can't say for sure right now, why boxing is happens in your code

Comment: @FrédéricDelanchy there is an existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683715/why-is-box-instruction-emitted-for-generic) which will explain, why boxing operation is performed for generic type argument. This, as well as my previous comment, can be a reason of performance difference. There is no boxing operation in non-generic variant

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I forgot to specify that even if my project targets the 4.7.2 .Net Framework, the installed Framework on my computer is the 4.8. I don't see any boxing in IL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET will only generate code for a generic method once for all reference types.  And that code must call through the `IMatrix` interface, as the various implementing types might implement the interface with different methods.  So it simply is an interface call.

However if you make Matrix a `struct` instead of a `class` the JITter will generate a type-specific implementation of the generic methods, and in that the interface call can be optimized away.

Comment: Just tested it : it works. Do you know why it can't generate a type-specific implementation with reference types ?

Comment: It's a performance tradeoff in JIT.  Imagine if `List<T>` generated different code for every type parameter.